# Bash printf: Clear entire line using Ctrl+U

Tags: bash, printf

I am trying to create a setup, using bash, which clears the line on command and prints a new one. Currently, I have this:

```
printf "\r                                                        \r$1"
```

Which looks quite silly and stops working if $1 becomes a long enough string.

If I have a line in my terminal and then press `Ctrl+U`, this line goes away.
I want to use Ctrl+U. I figured out using `xev` that the hex code of this is 0x15. So:

```
printf "\x15$1"
```

Seems to be the right idea, right? It does not work on my machine, the `\x15` is just ignored and the new string is printed right after the old one. Can I make this work?

Comment: Control-U is part of input editing, it has nothing to do with output.

Comment: Maybe use the ```\b``` to delete formerly output? Like: ```(printf ${USER} && (sleep 2; printf "\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b%s" ${TERM}))```

Comment: But this could be better: ```(printf ${USER} && (sleep 2; printf "\r%s" ${TERM}))``` Look: https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uprintf.htm at: Interpreted Escaped Character Sequences

Comment: @Barmar You should not post answers as comments. It is the correct answer, but I cannot mark it, since it is a comment.

Comment: I didn't think it was an answer, the question is based on a misunderstanding.

Comment: @Barmar So what do you think should happen to this question?

Comment: I was hoping someone would give a correct answer using ANSI escape sequences or the `tput` command. Have you searched for one of those solutions?